# Spring-data-jpa- issue on query validation ( related to DATAJPA-350 )

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Ours is a spring-data-jpa application and we are facing an issue on query validation during the application startup.

We were using **spring-data-jpa 1.3** version.

Due to an usecase we have made restructuring to our domain model like follows.

We had an Entity 'AnEntity' and after restructuring we made 'AnEntity' as an abstract class ( not any mapped superclass ) and introduced 2 child entities 'B_Entity' and 'C_Entity'. However for minimal impact on our application, we have not touched any named query or application logic defined in the system. Our use case demands a few runtime changes to the way user requests an entity. (Ex: User still request 'AnEntity' , but during runtime we decide whether to return 'B_Entity' or 'C_Entity'). We use custom RepositoryFactory Implementation and We have our own proxy for EntityManager and related JPA Classes, which will help to intercept the JPA Calls ( query execution go via our proxies ).

So on application startup, in order to avoid validation errors, a named query defined like 'select a from AnEntity' will be transformed as 'select a from A_Entity' ( via custom repostory implemenation and proxy classes ) and saved in the memory.  And then according to the user request, we decide whether to return A_Entity or B_Entity at runtime.

Now we have decided to upgrade to **spring-data-jpa 1.10.1**. But unfortunately, there is a new validation done by org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJPAQuery which takes a new EntityManager, instead of using already passed EntityManager ( which is an instance of our proxy ). So we have lost the handle to intercept the query and validation fails and application fails too.

We have seen the introduction of explicit EntityManager has been due to https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-350.

Is there anyway we can bypass this validation?. The only way we can see right now is create a proxy for EntityManagerFactory as well, but it may create a lot of unwanted objects and we are afraid it will bring unwanted complexity which we might not be able to recover from.

Now we are stuck, and any help is appreciated.